# Expand children menu items with parent link, without javascript

Tags: 7, routes

I've build a main-menu, and a sub-menu with [Menu block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block). The sub-menu shows up if I'm on the article with the represented link. It works like it should.

**Question**: How can can I expand all childrens of a parent menu-link without Javascript?

A short [wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XL4L.png) for the overview.

Comment: try [superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then setting the parent link to "Show as expanded" should get you the desired result. You can see the option when you go to Structure -> Menus -> list links (of the correct menu) -> edit (the parent menu item which should have it's child links always displayed).